# Django SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY set but the HttpOnly flag does not show up on cookies

Tags: django, apache, cookies, django-sessions, cookie-httponly

I've set this variable in the settings file like this:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

but when I open the website with Google Chrome `HttpOnly` does not show up in `set-cookie`.

My webserver is Apache2.4, and the website is using Https protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly). Add it to your setting:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

PLease note that this will make sending AJAX requests a little harder. You will have to pull it from the page instead of getting it from the cookie.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I added this and HttpOnly appeard on csrf. I'v also set HTTP_SESSION_SECURE, but ;secure also does not show up.

Comment: @Navid777 maybe you mean [CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure)?

Comment: I want to set ;HttpOnly and ;Secure on all cookies, not only on csrf. what should I do?

Comment: @Navid777 try adding `SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/;HttpOnly'` as well